# question form of the modal verbs in different structures

Tags: modal-verbs

Can I use such kind of question forms in the Past perfect form?

> Had I had to be sent there?-Passive Voice

> Had I had to have my car washed?-Passive Causative

> Had I had to have guns?-the main meaning of verb "To have"

Comment: There are no modal auxiliaries in your examples. What makes you think there are?

Answer (score 1):

Avoid all these expressions.

They are all valid, and formed by correct manipulation from

> I have to be sent there

> I have to have my car washed.

> I have to have guns.

These are correct and reasonably idiomatic (though the last one is a little odd).

Shifting each one into the past perfect and inverting the auxiliary verb to make a question is valid grammar.  But the combination of tenses and repeated use of the word "have" makes each one nearly incomprehensible.  English is hard enough, there's no need to make it harder.  So grammatically correct, but no, you can't use these question forms (if you want people to understand you)

Answer (score 0):

When you form questions in English, the *do+infintive* is used.

> I need 3 pieces of candy -> Do you need 3 pieces of candy.

If the verb is *be*, then it is used instead of *do* ...

> I am Spartacus -> Am I Spartacus (not *Do I be Spartacus?*)

Some other words also "take over" for the *do*, including

- Modals - I must go to the park -> Must I go to the park?
- *Have* when it's part of perfect constructions - I have told Sally to stop -> Have I told Sally to stop?

Note that *have to X* is not part of a perfect construction and not subject to this condition.

- I have to tell Sally to stop -> Do I have to tell Sally to stop?

So in your examples the initial *had* needs to be *did*, and the second *had* needs to be *have*.